# Mackey-glass regression experiments

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, spatio-temporal

So I'm running some experiments using long-short term memory networks for temporal sequence regression, and one of the sequences I have to use is generated using the mackey-glass differential equation. To make it comparable to another temporal sequence prediction algorithm, we have to use the same protocol as [this other paper] for training and testing, as always.

Thing is, mackey glass seems to be deterministic since there are no random variables, and [this other paper] trains their algorithm on the first 6000 points (with the initial transient cut off). They then test on 50 new sequences of 250 points each. But I'm hard pressed to understand how you have 50 "new"  test sequences, other than just generating >250*50 new samples (presumably with t>training set samples), and then just chopping that up whichever way.

Any ideas?

Context:

[image]

Comment: you probably forgot to include the link to _this other paper_.

Comment: good point. derp.

http://bit.ly/zhuenC